# C++ typedef and templates syntax?

Tags: templates, c++11, typedef, variadic

I was reading this [tutorial](http://mattbolt.blogspot.com.br/2014/04/c11-variadic-templates.html) on variadic templates, but in below code:

```
 template<int index, class C>
struct container_index {

  // points to the "next" container type 
  typedef typename container_index<
    index-1,
    typename C::base_container
  >::container_type container_type;

  // points to the next T-type 
  typedef typename container_index<
    index-1,
    typename C::base_container
  >::type type;
};
```

these typedefs seems redundant but it compiles well. The problem is simply I dont understand why they are like this and I didnt find a tutorial explaining this case. Could someone give some explanation? Why the typedef name is repeated:

```
"::container_type container_type;"

 "::type type;"
```

It couldn't be just like that:

```
typedef typename container_index<
        index-1,
        typename C::base_container
      >  type;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Because of recursion? See also the discussion in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913554/c-typedef-and-templates-syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example demonstrates a recursive type definition in templates. The key is that the recursion base case is specified as a specialisation for index=0:

```
template<class C>
struct container_index<0, C> {

    // point to C instead of C::base_container
    typedef C container_type;

    // point to C::type instead of C::base_container::type
    typedef typename C::type type;
};
```

It is this base-case that makes the type deduction possible. So for example, the type container_index<2, MyCont>::container_type is expanded to container_index<1, MyCont>::container_type, which in turn expands to container_index<0, MyCont>::container_type, which finally expands to MyCont.

Comment: I understand it now. As long as the "C" class have this "type"(like typedef T type) all type deduction will occur.
This part was confusing me more.
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` gives a type a name. So you need to supply both the type and the name you want to give it.

In

`typedef typename container_index<index-1, typename C::base_container>::type type;`

the `typename container_index<index-1, typename C::base_container>::type` is us describing the type we want to give a name to, and that final `type` before the semicolon is the name we want to call it.

Compare:

```
struct Example
{
    typedef Fruit::orange citrus; // declare a type called Example::citrus, which is the same type as Fruit::orange
    typedef Fruit::apple apple; // declare a type called Example::apple, which is the same type as Fruit::apple - the same operation as the line above, and so the same syntax!
};
```

Comment: What I dont undestant is that it seems the programmer is typedefing a type that doesnt exists:

typedef typename container_index<index-1, typename C::base_container>::type type;

Programmer is typedefing new type named "type" based on the old type named "type" that doesnt exists in container_index template?

Comment: Sergio: the specialisation struct container_index<0, C> a little further down in the tutorial provides a concrete type, that exists, as a starting point, and everything else becomes defined by altering that.